Is a transitive-on-unit-vectors subgroup of $SO(3)$ automatically all of $SO(3)$?
I have a physics background, and I am reading Ernest B. Vinberg's Linear Representations of Groups. He briefly uses a lemma that states:

Let $F$ be a subgroup of $SO(3)$ with the following properties:

$F$ acts transitively on the unit sphere, i.e., any given unit vector can be taken into any other such vector by a suitable
transformation belonging to $F$
There is an axis such that $F$ contains all rotations about that axis.

Then $F=SO(3)$.

This is a nice lemma, and straightforwardly proved in the text. To recapitulate the proof: let the axis be about some vector $a$. For any $r \in SO(3)$, we can take the vector $a$ to the vector $ra$ via some $r'$ in $F$, i.e. there is some $r'$ such that $r'a = ra$ (this follows from $1$). Then by $2$, we see that $(r')^{-1} r$ is in $F$. $F$ is a subgroup, and so because it contains both $r'$ and $(r')^{-1} r$, it contains their product of $r$. Thus $F$ contains all of $SO(3)$.
This proof is nice.
However, there is something small that is bothering me. It seems to me that only condition $1$ should be needed to argue that $F$ is $SO(3)$, since transitive-ness on the unit sphere is such a strong condition! However, the proof of the above lemma uses condition $2$ in an essential way.

Is it true that I can remove condition $2$? That is, if $F$ is a subgroup of $SO(3)$ that acts transitively on the unit sphere, then $F$ is $SO(3)$?

First of all, the group $G=SO(3)$ is simple as an abstract group: This fact was discussed several times on this site (see, say, here). Let's prove that your group $F$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, i.e. with every rotation $R$, the group $F$ contains all rotations conjugate to $R$ (i.e. all rotations with the same angle as $R$). The rotation $R$ fixes a unit vector $v$. Let $G_v$ denote the stabilizer of $v$ in $G$, i.e. the group of all rotations fixing $v$. Then $G=FG_v$, i.e. every $g\in G$ is a composition $f\circ h$, where $f\in F$, $h\in G_v$; this follows from transitivity of the action of $F$ on the unit sphere. Thus,
$$
gR g^{-1}= f h R h^{-1} f^{-1}= f R  f^{-1},
$$
since $h$ and $R$ commute. Hence, the rotation $gR g^{-1}$ also belongs to $F$. Thus, $F$ is a normal subgroup of $G$. By simplicity of $G$, it follows that either $F=G$ or $F=\{1\}$. The latter is clearly impossible. Thus, $F=G$.
